# Navigation and the Case of the Missing Drop Down

Tags: javascript, css

I created a nice little menu with mouseovers and a drop down menu.

The navigation code is simple:

```
        <ul class="menu" id="menu">
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="about">About</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">Our History</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Our Process</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Portfolio</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Financing</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Testimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Subcontractors</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="maintenance">Maintenance</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="testimonials">Testimonials</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" class="menulink" id="contact">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
```

In isolation it works as it should: http://www.rouviere.com/nav/

However, when I put it in place: http://www.rouviere.com/jr/ the drop down menu under **About** stays hidden.

I would appreciate a helping hand here to figure out why the drop down menu doesn't show.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the line `p=h.getElementsByTagName('a')[0]` you are referring to the About link by index. This works on your test page, but your real page has a new anchor tag on the main logo, which comes before the About link in the HTML. You should give your About link an `id` attribute and refer to it in your JavaScript.

Comment: Is there another type of work around, since I need the option to be able to add the drop down menu to any of the main navigation elements?

Thanks.

Comment: sure, you can use a class name on all the nav elements to which you want to add the menu. then find/process them with jquery `$('a.menu').each(function(i,el){ /* stuff */ })` for example.